# Mirror modifier is active after applying

Tags: mirror-modifier

I don't know if this is a bug. After I applied the mirror modifier on a half sphere, the sphere was acting like I didn't hit the apply button but I could edit the mesh from both sides. I thought this wouldn't be a problem because I only needed the sphere to cut another mesh. But when I applied the boolean modifier the new mesh still had the same problem even though it's not symmetrical.

[image: Before I edit the mesh]

[image: Edit from one side]

[image]

I haven't used any other modifiers when I applied the mirror and I never entered the sculpt mode.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have the Mirror option activated? Could you please share your file?

Comment: I enabled Proportional Editing to show you the mirroring. The Proportional Editing does not have mirror option

Comment: @moonboots I added the blend file

Comment: Your Blend file only has a single 'Face' object in it whereas your images show that you have three enabled in the outliner (and other disabled ones) . Are you sure that you're editing the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Mirror* option is activated, disable it (not sure why you don't have it on the top right, but you can find it in the *N panel > Tool > Options*):

[image]

Comment: It's there (and turned on) without the N panel open in this 3.2.2 version.

Comment: Yes but in his screenshot we can't see it, why that?

Comment: It looks as if he's using version 2.83.0 (bottom right corner of his images). I can't remember where that setting was in that version.